# Run Command Line Arguments in a loop in Python

Tags: python, function, loops, command-line-arguments

I have a program that calls a function from a module and uses command line arguments (sys.argv). I want to call this function multiple times with difference set of values for these arguments. I'm basically trying to use a loop to run this but it is not working:

```
test_args = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
i = 0
while i < len(test)args)+1:
    sys.argv = test_args[i]
    module.function()
    i=i+1
```

I tried for loop and even while loop, but the iteration stops after the first iteration. The first iteration though runs successfully but doesn't proceed to the next iteration i.e i = i+1

Is there a way to run this in loop?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

As you didn't mention the `function` present in the module. I have created sum function as an example.

Here is the code

```
import sys #if you directly take input from system arguments
def addall(a):
    return sum(a)
test_args = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
for i in test_args:
    print (i, addall(i))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3] 6
[4, 5, 6] 15
[7, 8, 9] 24
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The module here is another python script (let's say - sample.py) and the function within that script (let's say - test()) The function "test" does not take any argument (as defined) but uses command line arguments and parse them using argparser. Basically, generating all arguments required for the module "sample.py" dynamically. Now, the issue is i want the sys.argv to take multiple values based on the values of i and run in loop but it stops after running once.

Comment: I am bit confused, what you are expecting. Do you need to take `n` number of inputs through sys.args? If yes, you can get values as input in program and append to a list. or you can take values in comma separted or tab space separated. Or else even you can pass file name as argument and process it in the program.

Comment: Basically the function takes 12 arguments. I want to test the function for different set of these 12 arguments. I already appending the list. The "test_args" is the list of all different set of arguments or in simple words this is how it looks:  test_args = [[a1, b1, c1, .... l1], [a2,b2,c2, .... l2] , ... [an, bn, cn, ... ln]]. Now, while iterating, first iteration should take [a1, b1, c1, .... l1] , second iteration should take [ a2, b2, c2, ... l2] and so on. But my code right now sys.argv takes first iteration correctly as [a1, b1, c1, .... l1] but stops there and doesn't proceed further.

Comment: The function is defined in a way that it doesn't take any arguments i.e. test() but the function uses argparser to parse the system arguments provided in command line arguments to generate parameters dynamically.

Comment: My code works for what you need. If it is not proceeding to the second loop, try adding an extra loop at the top (surely wrong way) or check your function properly(which might be the problem)

Comment: You may need to check the `argparse` for your program error in the function. I am not sure of it unless I see the program.